# Remove duplicates by multiple conditions

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, tidyverse

I have data where an individual (Name) appears multiple times in a eggphase category. I would like for there only to be one sample per individual but I don't just want to keep the first one the R finds. I would like to keep the one where the group appears most in all other categories. Hopefully my example helps make this clear.

```
library(tidyverse)
myDF <- read.table(text="Tissue Food Eggphase Name Group
  wb fl after Kia a
  wb fl after Kia c
  wb wf before Kia b
  wb fl before Lucy c
  wb fl after Lucy b
  wb fl after Lucy c
  wb fl yolkdep Jess c
  wb fl yolkdep Betty a
  wb fl yolkdep Betty b", header = TRUE)
```

I would like to just keep the rows where Name appears once grouped by Tissue, Food and Eggphase BUT I want to select the row where Group appears in most if not all different eggphases (with the same Tissue and Food combinations).

```
   #results I want
  Tissue Food Eggphase  Name Group
1     wb   fl    after   Kia     c
2     wb   wf   before   Kia     b
3     wb   fl   before  Lucy     c
4     wb   fl    after  Lucy     c
5     wb   fl  yolkdep  Jess     c
6     wb   fl  yolkdep Betty     b
```

I tried

```
one_bird <- myDF %>% 
  distinct(Tissue, Food, Eggphase, Name, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

but it only keeps the first entry

```
  Tissue Food Eggphase  Name Group
1     wb   fl    after   Kia     a
2     wb   wf   before   Kia     b
3     wb   fl   before  Lucy     c
4     wb   fl    after  Lucy     b
5     wb   fl  yolkdep  Jess     c
6     wb   fl  yolkdep Betty     b
```

Any ideas in how to tell it select the row where `Group`appears in most (if not all) of the eggphases within a `Tissue` `Food` combination? 
In my example the group that appears the most within the `Tissue` and `Food` combination of `wb` and `fl` is `c` and `b` but `Kia` doesn't appear in `Group` `b` and so `c` is a better option. Like this example, my data has duplicates which are from groups which are not the most common `Group`, how do I make it choose next most common just for that row?

I hope I have made enough sense.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to create a frequency column grouped by 'Tissue', 'Food', 'Group', and then do a descending `arrange` on 'n' and use `distinct`

```
library(dplyr)
myDF %>%
     group_by(Tissue, Food, Group) %>%
     mutate(n = n()) %>% arrange(Tissue, Food, Eggphase, Name, desc(n)) %>% 
     ungroup %>%
     distinct(Tissue, Food, Eggphase, Name, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
     select(-n)
```

Comment: Thank you, its getting on the right track, but the problem in my real data is that there are 20 entries for each `Group` as I sampled the same birds each time I sampled. If I include `Eggphase` I get closer to what I want except that I don't know what coverage of `Eggphase` each group has. This code: `eggphaseCount <- with(myDF,aggregate(x=list(Group_phaseCt=Eggphase),by=list(Group=Group),FUN=function(x) length(unique(x))))` from Nate is the idea I'm going for and there may be multiple groups with a max of 4 so I then it it shouldn't matter which I choose.

Comment: @mckisa  It's okay.  You should choose the one what works best for you

Answer (score 0):

I guess this post and answer should give me reason to learn dplyr and tidyverse, but since I've put in the effort to give a answer that works, here it is:

```
myDF <- read.table(text="Tissue Food Eggphase Name Group
  wb fl after Kia a
  wb fl after Kia c
  wb wf before Kia b
  wb fl before Lucy c
  wb fl after Lucy b
  wb fl after Lucy c
  wb fl yolkdep Jess c
  wb fl yolkdep Betty a
  wb fl yolkdep Betty b", header = TRUE)

# I usually have the following setting active: options(stringsAsFactors=F)
# The following might error without such a setting

# Create a var that indicates a duplicate or a record with a duplicate
myDF$duplicate <- duplicated(myDF[,c('Name','Eggphase','Tissue','Food')])
myDF$duplicate <- ifelse(duplicated(myDF[,c('Name','Eggphase','Tissue','Food')],fromLast=T),yes=T, no=myDF$duplicate)

# Count eggphases by group 
eggphaseCount <- with(myDF,aggregate(x=list(Group_phaseCt=Eggphase),by=list(Group=Group),FUN=function(x) length(unique(x))))
# Merge to DF
myDF <- merge(myDF,eggphaseCount,by='Group',all=T)

# Get the max # of egphases by name
scale <- with(myDF,aggregate(x=list(PhaseMax=Group_phaseCt),by=list(Name=Name),FUN=max))
# Add to DF
myDF <- merge(myDF,scale,by='Name',all=T)

# Take the ratio
myDF$bestRatio <- with(myDF,Group_phaseCt/PhaseMax)
# Keep only those that aren't a duplicate, or are a duplicate and have the highest ratio
myDF2 <- myDF[with(myDF,which(duplicate==FALSE | (duplicate==TRUE & bestRatio==1))),]
```

Comment: This is really cool. My knowledge of this syntax is unfortunately non-existent. I understand what your code does, but I'm not sure I can edit it. I tried running it on my data and but it includes all the rows where the ratio is 1 instead of just 1 row. In this case I also want all of the chosen rows to be of the same group. 
I tried `myDF2$dup2 <- duplicated(myDF2[,c('Name','Eggphase','Tissue','Food')])`
`myDF2 %>% filter(dup2 == FALSE)` but it gives me one less row than `one_bird <- myDF %>% 
  distinct(Tissue, Food, Eggphase, Name, .keep_all = TRUE)` making me question its accuracy.Ideas?

Comment: Yes, on another inspection I see that in the example data that my code doesn't eliminate ties between groups as you mentioned.  If I were to fix it, I would go back in and edit the code to have the logic to pic the line with the group matching the group of later phases or something like that.  That would make my unwieldy code even longer, and since you seem to have arrived at a solution, I'll move on.  Congrats!

Answer (score 0):

Hey thanx for your guys help!! A combination of what you suggested seems to have worked:

```
# Create a var that indicates a duplicate or a record with a duplicate
myDF$duplicate <- duplicated(myDF[,c('Name','Eggphase','Tissue','Food')])
#this won't tell you that the first entry og the combination is double
# so need to make them check against the previous row
myDF$duplicate <- ifelse(duplicated(myDF[,c('Name','Eggphase','Tissue','Food')],fromLast=T),yes=T, no=myDF$duplicate)

# Count eggphases by group 
eggphaseCount <- with(myDF,aggregate(x=list(Group_phaseCt=Eggphase),by=list(Group=Group),FUN=function(x) length(unique(x))))
# Merge to DF
myDF <- merge(myDF,eggphaseCount,by='Group',all=T)

# Get the max # of egphases by name
scale <- with(myDF,aggregate(x=list(PhaseMax=Group_phaseCt),by=list(Name=Name),FUN=max))
# Add to DF
myDF <- merge(myDF,scale,by='Name',all=T)

# Take the ratio
myDF$bestRatio <- with(myDF,Group_phaseCt/PhaseMax)

# make new df without duplicates
myDF2 <- myDF %>% 
#arrange in a way that the first duplicate is from the group with the most eggphases
#and the name appears in the most egg phases 
  arrange(Tissue, Food, Eggphase, Name, Group, desc(Group_phaseCt), desc(PhaseMax)) %>% 
#select only distinct rows according to specified var keep all others
  distinct(Tissue, Food, Eggphase, Name, .keep_all = TRUE)
```