# Removing duplicate values based on multiple conditions

Tags: r, dplyr

I need help filtering out values based on several conditions.

So let’s say there is one city that overlaps two separate counties, so that there are two separate values. The second value is the same city, but with a small population, that represents that city’s overlap into the second county. So variables include city, population, school district, school district expenditure, crime count, etc. and I want to keep all values where a city and a school district are unique (so observations of city may repeat), but I don’t want two observations of the same city when it represents county overlap (because then I’ll end up with a smaller population that will be misrepresentative and it will scuttle everything else). To complicate things, cities also repeat by year (since I want to keep my dput short, you won't be able to see this).

So

```r
    dat%>%distinct(city, school district, year .keep all = TRUE)
```

would get me all unique values, but there’s still two issues: 1) I want to make sure that the larger population is the one that is kept (unless the overlap is near half…maybe over 30% with regard to population), and 2) the other part of the city in the second county might attend another school district, in which case it would still be recorded as distinct with my current code.

I could then run distinct again…as dat%>%distinct(city, year, .keep all = TRUE) but then I'd also get rid of cities where there are repeating observations representing different school districts, and I can’t do distinct by school district, because there are school districts which might be attended by several cities. So I think making it conditional on the larger population would be the way to go, but I’m not sure how to do that.

I found this post: [Remove duplicates by multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47267725/remove-duplicates-by-multiple-conditions)

and tried something similar, but to no avail:

```
    dat%>%
         group_by(PLACE_ID, COUNTY_ID, full_district_id, year)%>%
         mutate(n = n())%>%
      arrange(PLACE_ID, year, desc(n)) %>% 
      ifelse(n>1, distinct(PLACE_ID,.keep_all = TRUE, PLACE_ID)%>%
         ungroup()
```

I get this error:

```
    Error in ifelse(., n > 1, distinct(PLACE_ID, .keep_all = TRUE), PLACE_ID) : unused argument (PLACE_ID)
```

Thanks, much!

Here's the dput (note that the two values that do repeat, should both be kept because it is same city different school districts; I can't find an example of repeating city values I don't want, given that that is pretty near the answer to my question)

```
structure(list(PLACE_ID = c("0100124", "0100460", "0101228", 
"0101708", "0102116", "0102260", "0102320", "0102320", "0102836", 
"0102860"), CITY = c("abbeville", "adamsville", "aliceville", 
"andalusia", "arab", "ardmore", "argo", "argo", "ashford", "ashland"
), COUNTY_ID = c("01067", "01073", "01107", "01039", "01095", 
"01083", "01073", "01115", "01069", "01027"), full_district_id = c("0101740", 
"0101920", "0102730", "0100060", "0100100", "0102100", "0101920", 
"0103062", "0101770", "0100750"), POPULATION.EST = c(2882, 4841, 
2581, 8901, 7503, 1042, 2692, 2692, 1905, 2035), year = c(2003, 
2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003), EXPENDITURE_PER_STUDENT = c(6.91392685629849, 
5.93085371942087, 6.58799048751486, 6.23839541547278, 5.89238165680473, 
6.22123450607237, 5.93085371942087, 5.45296752519597, 5.5939837398374, 
6.11974248927039), CRIME_TOTAL = c(105, 365, 4, 734, 632, 19, 
44, 44, 26, 14)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: `dat %>%
  group_by(PLACE_ID, COUNTY_ID, full_district_id, year) %>%
  slice(which.max(POPULATION.EST))
` would select row with max `POPULATION.EST` in each group.

Comment: Thanks, Ronak. Just tried it. The code did seem to remove a lot of values (nearly 50,000 of 170,000). I know slice in the sense of slice(1:10), or to pick out rows; I didn't know it could also be used with group_by...which is a neat use. There's no way that it could be removing other values though? Just want to make sure.

Comment: Actually I don't understand what is your selection criteria for rows. Using `slice` and `which.max` we only get max row with Population in each group.